# Javascript variable scope issue

Tags: javascript, target, var, scoping

I have a simple scoping issue that is eluding me.

Here is a simpler version of the code but employs the same principle.

```
function myFunction(){
  $('.selector_1, .selector_2').click(function(e){
    var $trgt = $(e.target);
    var myVAR;

    if ($trgt.is('.selector_1')){
      myVAR = 'selector_1';
    }

    if ($trgt.is('.selector_2')){
      myVAR = 'selector_2';
    }
    console.log(myVAR);
  }
}
```

The issue is, if the user were to click on `selector_1` `myVAR` would get populated successfully every time, however, the 2nd target handler will always return `myVAR` as undefined.

I'm assuming this is a programming 101 type thing, I have yet to find a straightforward answer, however.

Thanks for taking a look at this! Criticism openly appreciated.

Comment: works here: http://jsfiddle.net/xaGpW/

Comment: Please post your markup!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your html is probably something like this:

```
<div class='selector_1'>HELLO</div>

<div class='selector_2'><span>HI THERE</span></div>
```

So when you click on the second one you get undefined bacause the target is the span and not the selector.

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/M6fYf/

Comment: Combining Adam Rackis solution and Neal's, you get this: http://jsfiddle.net/M6fYf/4/  Which works.  ;)

Comment: Thank you for all of your responses. I'm examining my selectors more closely, however the 'this' I have returns the proper HTMLAnchorElement. 

i.e: 'if($trgt.is('#mDiv li a')){
        myVAR = $(this).attr('href');
      }'

Comment: @Ken that is hard to read in the comment. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You all were right, it was my selector, turns out using an 'a' for a click selector can be a bad idea depending on if it has any nested elements as the actual area to respond to the click can be reduced to invisibility. For example, an image inside of an <a>, if you chose the a as the click selector it will technically never fire.

Comment: Also, not sure why it took so long for me to think of this, but the easiest way to troubleshoot a target selector is console.log(trgt), realized what element was actually being clicked according to the browser. I completely attribute this to insufficient caffeine levels.

Answer (score 2):

That code *should* work.  Maybe `e.target` isn't behaving properly for some element types???  Instead of `e.target`, try using `this`

```
function myFunction(){
  $('.selector_1, .selector_2').click(function(e){
    var $trgt = $(this);
    var myVAR;

    if ($trgt.is('.selector_1')){
      myVAR = 'selector_1';
    }

    if ($trgt.is('.selector_2')){
      myVAR = 'selector_2';
    }
    console.log(myVAR);
  }
}
```

Comment: @nybbler - I originally kept selecting $(this) over and over -- I changed it to keep OPs $trgt variable, but set it to $(this) - same effect, but without re-selecting $(this) over and over